# Calculating when all rooms are busy

Tags: php, datetime

Let's say we have two bookable rooms - *Room 1* and *Room 2*. The rooms arn't visible during booking, but are automatically distributed when the user books a room. We want to calculate which times both are booked at the same time. In other words - what time is no room available.

The problem is when we add a third room - *Room 3* - it won't work anymore, as it only compares two rooms. How do I adjust (or completely replace) the logic so the number of rooms can be variable?

**Input:**

```
<?php
$busy_rooms = array (
  'room_1' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'from' => 
      DateTime::__set_state(array(
         'date' => '2017-10-02 11:00:00.000000',
         'timezone_type' => 1,
         'timezone' => '+02:00',
      )),
      'to' => 
      DateTime::__set_state(array(
         'date' => '2017-10-02 12:00:00.000000',
         'timezone_type' => 1,
         'timezone' => '+02:00',
      )),
    ),
  ),
  'room_2' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'from' => 
      DateTime::__set_state(array(
         'date' => '2017-10-02 09:00:00.000000',
         'timezone_type' => 1,
         'timezone' => '+02:00',
      )),
      'to' => 
      DateTime::__set_state(array(
         'date' => '2017-10-02 16:00:00.000000',
         'timezone_type' => 1,
         'timezone' => '+02:00',
      )),
    )
  )
);
```

In the example above, no room is available between 11:00-12:00 that particular day. The current logic seems to handle this correctly.

**Current logic:**

```
<?php
$busy_times = array()

foreach($busy_rooms as $a_id => $a_busy_times) {
    foreach($busy_rooms as $b_id => $b_busy_times) {

        // Never compare a room with itself
        if($b_id === $a_id) continue;

        foreach($a_busy_times as $a_busy) {
            foreach($b_busy_times as $b_busy) {

                // B within A
                //    |--B--|
                // |-----A-----|
                if($b_busy['from'] >= $a_busy['from'] && $b_busy['to'] <= $a_busy['to']) {
                    $busy_times[] = array(
                        'from' => clone $b_busy['from'],
                        'to' => clone $b_busy['to']
                    );
                }

                // B-from within A, B-to after A
                //    |--B--|
                // |--A--|
                elseif($b_busy['from'] >= $a_busy['from'] && $b_busy['to'] >= $a_busy['to'] && $b_busy['from'] <= $a_busy['to']) {
                    $busy_times[] = array(
                        'from' => clone $b_busy['from'],
                        'to' => clone $a_busy['to']
                    );
                }

                // B-from before A, B-to within A
                // |--B--|
                //    |--A--|
                elseif($b_busy['from'] <= $a_busy['from'] && $b_busy['to'] <= $a_busy['to'] && $b_busy['to'] >= $a_busy['from']) {
                    $busy_times[] = array(
                        'from' => clone $b_busy['from'],
                        'to' => clone $a_busy['to']
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** (contents of `$busy_times`):

```
<?php
array (
  array (
    'from' => 
    DateTime::__set_state(array(
       'date' => '2017-10-02 11:00:00.000000',
       'timezone_type' => 1,
       'timezone' => '+02:00',
    )),
    'to' => 
    DateTime::__set_state(array(
       'date' => '2017-10-02 12:00:00.000000',
       'timezone_type' => 1,
       'timezone' => '+02:00',
    )),
  )
);
```